# how to inspect the footer of a website with Firefox GCLI plugin?

Tags: firefox, browser, html, wordpress, browser-plugin

How do I use [GCLI](http://mozilla.github.io/gcli/) to view the footer for a wordpress blog?  Typically, the footer isn't viewable because as you scroll down, older items are loaded to the page.  While not infinite, for practical purposes it's not possible to scroll to the bottom of the page.

Can [GCLI](http://mozilla.github.io/gcli/) display or inspect the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably possible, but it would be much easier to simply open the developer tools click the gear to open the dev tools preferences, then disable js. then the page won't load more content and you can easily scroll to the bottom and right click to inspect whatever you want.